# Why Eclipse CDT is building unrelated project and configuration?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have a workspace with multiple projects. And each with multiple config.
One project has 3 configurations, A, B and C. A and B are libs and have no reference to other project, C is a unit test exe with references.
When compiling A by clicking the arrow on the side of the build button and selecting A, C is also compiled, and config A of other projects are also compiled.

In the settings, I have (sorry can't use imgur, blocked at office):
https://framapic.org/JNPehQjNiGAB/mQZRXwGiK6Jl

What I want, is that when asking to compile config A on one project, it sticks to compiling only config A on only this project.

Answer (score 0):

After days and days and days I found the bug causing this madness.

We have 2 project references management when using eclipse CDT.
One under Properties->Project References which is native eclipse I think.
One under Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->References.

I have a target which indeed has references set up in the C/C++ section. When using this target, it fills the native Project References with the used references.

The issue is when I switch back to a target without references, the native Project References is not updated!!!!

Workaround: pull out the target with references and make an stand alone project for this target alone.

Comment: Interesting analysis. Did you open a bug to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT about it?

Comment: What's the point? Many bugs related to dependencies detection from 2010 or earlier are still there… no need to add more on a dying product, do we?

Comment: CDT is not dying, CDT is not a product but an OSS project. So yes, there is a point in opening bugs. If you don't open bugs when you find them and most other do the same, don't be surprised and if there are still some bugs.